# How to determine the source of sub-nm periodic error in NIR spectra

Tags: analytical-chemistry, spectroscopy, spectrophotometry

I've run into an issue collecting measurements on deionized water in the $1050-\pu{1200 nm}$ range. To determine the sensitivity of my spectrophotometer in this range, I've acquired measurements on pure deionized water in double-beam mode using two identical quartz cuvettes. I have taken measurements at several time steps near $\pu{1064 nm}$, from $0.1-\pu{100 s}$ per time-point and constant $\pu{0.1 nm}$ per step and $\pu{2 nm}$ bandwidth. I keep finding that the baseline standard deviation (SD) does not improve beyond $1.4 \times 10^{-4}$ Abs.

This value is technically below the acceptable qualification values of $2 \times 10^{-4}$ Abs in that range, but I'm trying to determine if this is the ultimate noise level of the instrument in this range or if these periodic variations are due to a mechanical issue in the monochromator like a lead screw, or due to environmental or electrical line noise of some kind.

[image]

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I had that happen with a UV spec once. If I recall correctly, the culprit was the chopper motor. Check if the frequency matches up.

Comment: The periodic variation appears to show 10 steps per nm and your step size is 0.1 nm per step. Perhaps try a different step size and see what happens to the periodicity.

Comment: Interesting problem. You can try a couple of things. I assume that you already have the raw data exported in Excel or MATLAB. Something which we traditionally neglect is the error in the x-axis itself. For each export wavelength, plot the difference of wavelength vs. data number. Do you see a pattern or not? If it is a true and constant sampling rate, it should be a perfect straight line. However, I recently had problems with microwave spectroscopy data and the x-axis "spacing" had a lot of jitter as they call it. It can be periodic too.

Comment: If your x-axis spacing is not "perfectly" identical, you might see this artifact as a function of integration time.

Comment: By “chopper motor” I meant the stepper motor which usually has a chopper drive.

Comment: What is also weird is that you have periodic noise as well.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that you are observing an optical etalon effect from reflections from the parallel faces of the cuvettes and the introduction of phase shifts that manifest themselves as the sinusoidal variations that you see in the wavelength space?